# SQL Retrieve distinct data by latest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table as follows:

```
Name    Customer   Date                     Amount
Joe       Aaron    2012-01-03 14:12:00.0      150
Joe       Aaron    2012-02-03 14:12:00.0      150
Joe       Danny    2012-03-03 14:12:00.0      150
Joe       Karen    2012-07-03 14:12:00.0      150
Ronald    Blake    2012-05-03 14:12:00.0      1501
```

I would like to query to retrieve data by specifying the `Name` and if there are duplicates for `Customer` column, the records for the latest `Date` is

For example, if I want to query `Joe`, I will get the following result:

```
Name    Customer   Date                     Amount
Joe       Aaron    2012-02-03 14:12:00.0      150
Joe       Danny    2012-03-03 14:12:00.0      150
Joe       Karen    2012-07-03 14:12:00.0      150
```

How should I do this? Tried `distinct` but it doesnt work that way.

**EDIT**
I'm using SQL Server. Sorry I re-edit my question and this should be the correct question that I am asking.

Comment: Please let us know which database you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server).  Also your dates (e.g. `11/12/2017`) look fishy.  Are you storing your dates as text?

Comment: Do your table have a PK?

Answer (score 0):

Did you Try this?

```
SELECT Name, Customer, MAX(Date) as CurrentDate, Amount 
FROM data 
Group By Name, Customer, Amount 
HAVING Name =  'Joe'
```

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (NAME, CUSTOMER, DATE) IN (SELECT NAME, CUSTOMER, MAX(DATE) WHERE NAME = 'Joe' GROUP BY NAME, CUSTOMER)
```

Comment: The OP added that info only after my answer was provided, but haven't answered my comment yet...

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using the WITH TIES clause in concert with Row_Number()

**Example**

```
Select top 1 with ties *
 From  YourTable
 Where Name='Joe'
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By Customer Order By Date Desc)
```

**Returns**

```
Name    Customer    Date                    Amount
Joe     Aaron       2012-02-03 14:12:00.000 150
Joe     Danny       2012-03-03 14:12:00.000 150
Joe     Karen       2012-07-03 14:12:00.000 150
```